# Conversion of android code to iOS for sending bitmap image input to phone-gap from native iOS plugin

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have tried many ways to send image input  to phone-gap from native iOS plugin.But end up with an issue ..please any one let me know where I have implemented wrong?

Here is My code for phonegap plugin Method:

```
 myPlugin.convertToFile("profileBase64Callback", citizen.profileImage,  function(){ }, function(){ });//citizen.profileImage is of type base64 data
```

**Using response image from native iOS to phonegap**

```
 function profileBase64Callback(imageURI){

   console.log("profileImage path :" + imageURI);

}
```

**android version native plugin file:**

```
       if(action.equals("convertToFile")){
        try{
               JSONObject json = args.getJSONObject(0);
               callbackFunction = (String) json.get("callback");
               String base64 = json.getString("base64");

                Log.d(TAG, "base64 content"+base64);
                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                String filePath = convertBitmapToFile(decodedByte);
                //callbackContext.success(requestId);
                sendData(filePath);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG + ": error in start: ", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        }
```

**//implementation for convertBitmapToFile in android**

```
   private String convertBitmapToFile(Bitmap photo)
   {
      File mypath = null;
      try {
        File dir;
            File storage = null;
            // =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {
                storage = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            }else if(Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null){
                storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            }

            dir = new File(storage.getAbsolutePath() + “/AppName/profilePicture");

            if (!dir.exists())
            {
                dir.mkdirs();
                File file = new File(dir, ".nomedia");
                if(!file.exists())
                    file.createNewFile();
            }

          String uniqueId = "AppName"+Utility.getCurrentDate()+"_"+Utility.getCurrentTime()+"_"+Math.random();
          String current = uniqueId + ".jpg";

          mypath = new File(dir, current);
          FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
          photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, mFileOutStream);
          ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          photo.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, stream);
          mFileOutStream.flush();
          mFileOutStream.close();

        return mypath.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I m getting the image at this method but profilepicture is in undefined when printed in javascript  method using console ..Can any one please tell me the conversion of above from  android iOS or which method should i use to convert image to decoded array ,bitmapimage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my Issue:

**Base64File.m**

```
- (void)convertToFile:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command{

    NSLog(@"--convertToFile Plugin");
    NSString *methodname1;
    NSDictionary* options = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    if ([command.arguments count] > 0) {
       options = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
       methodname1 =[options objectForKey:@"callback"];
 }

   //Now data is decoded. You can convert them to UIImage

   NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:methodname1 options:0];
   NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp/Test.png"]; // identity the home directory and file name

   [data writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

   NSString *appndStr = [@"file://" stringByAppendingString:jpgPath];
   NSLog(@"----appndStr--%@",appndStr);

   NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{
                               @"imagURI": appndStr,
                              };

    NSData* jsonData         = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:nil];

   //Generate the JSON String
    NSString* jsonString1   = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes]
                                                   length:[jsonData length]
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *echo = jsonString1;


   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"OK"];
       [pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:true];

       [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];

        //Send data to Javascript callback Method
        NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@);", @"profileBase64Callback", echo];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

    });

 }
```

**Profile.js**

```
  function profileBase64Callback(imageURI){
      console.log("profileImage path :" + imageURI.imagURI);
   }
```

**Console output :**

profileImage path **:file:///Users/samDesk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C8427646-AB64-4063-A7BE-57547DDA656E/data/Applications/DDD4B4DR-2803-4615-9EC9-5840EAAD6709/tmp/Test.png**